# Is better Razor diagnostics change now included in ServiceStack v3.9.45?

Tags: razor, servicestack

As I'm still getting HttpCompilationException (External Exception) when I work through Mono on Mac with no hint as to what the real error is within Razor. To test it I'm binding to an invalid property name in a model. If I use the correct property name it works.

The project has GitHub issue here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/561

Is this change now included in v3.9.45? Do I have to do anything extra to enable it? I've got DebugMode on but that just adds stack trace data.

Answer (score 1):

The Razor support was rewritten and my original change to improve the debugging experience wasn't carried forward (originally). It's now been added, see this comment:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/561#issuecomment-18204358

And this is the pull request that added it.
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/684

It was included as of 3.9.47